# Nested viewpager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I'm trying to implement layout like this:

[image]

I attached sample project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jEKOONMWN3MblLN1EmePsWTWNCNQVfN-/view?usp=sharing

The problem I have is that second view pager does not react to touch events.

Ideally, if user swipes right when "Two" tab is selected, second view pager would change page when user swipes - from picture, if "Forth" is selected, swipe right would select "Fifth" and swipe left would select "Third".
Swipe left from "Third" would lead to first view page selecting "One".

Is there a way to do this with view pager 2?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer - if someone wonders, I wrapped child viewpager2 with: https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ViewPager2/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/NestedScrollableHost.kt

Just without this "if" condition: https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ViewPager2/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/NestedScrollableHost.kt#L78

As child viewpager2 is wrapped in constraint layout.